# gpg: --armor vs --clearsign

Tags: gpg

gpg has an option `--armor`, which can generate output in an ASCII-armored format similar to uuencoded documents.

It also has an option `--clearsign` which causes the document to be wrapped
in an ASCII-armored signature.

How are they different? Can one be done alternatively in terms of the other? Thanks.

---

```
$ cat sleep.py
#! /usr/bin/python3
import time
time.sleep( 30 )

$ gpg --clearsign sleep.py  

$ cat sleep.py.asc
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA512

#! /usr/bin/python3
import time
time.sleep( 30 )
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
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=g9wE
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----


$ gpg --armor --detach-sign sleep.py
$ cat sleep.py.asc3
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
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=TyOB
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`--armor` is an output modifier: you use it in addition to other arguments which specify the operation you want `gpg` to perform, and it changes the output to be an ASCII-armored file instead of a binary file. Thus

```
gpg --armor --sign myfile
```

will sign `myfile` and output the signed file in `myfile.asc`, but none of the contents of `myfile` will be immediately visible in `myfile.asc`. (`gpg` compresses the contents by default, among other transformations.)

`--clearsign` is a complete operation: `gpg` signs the given file, and wraps the signature around the content without modifying it. Thus

```
gpg --clearsign myfile
```

will sign `myfile` and output the signed file in `myfile.asc`, in such a way that the original contents of `myfile` will be immediately visible in `myfile.asc`.

Clear-signing is ideal for signing emails or other text documents which should remain readable as-is, without involving `gpg`. Recipients can optionally verify the signature using `gpg`, but they don’t have to use `gpg` to read the contents.

You can approximate the result of `--clearsign` using `--armor` by producing a detached signature (`gpg --armor --detach-sign myfile`): if `gpg` doesn’t need to alter the signed content, then the detached signature will be identical to the signature block at the end of a clear-signed file. You’d need to add the appropriate header:

```
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA512
```

or whatever is appropriate.

Comment: Thanks. " it changes the output to be an ASCII-armored file instead of a binary file". What is relation between an ASCII-armored file and a binary file?

Comment: Found it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding

Comment: Why are `gpg --armor --detach-sign myfile` and the signature in `gpg --clearsign myfile` still different?

Comment: The native OpenPGP format uses arbitrary octets. ASCII-armored files represent this data by encoding it using Base64, along with a checksum and header lines describing the data. See [RFC 4880, section 6.2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4880#section-6.2) for details.

Comment: They’re different because their contents aren’t the same. A detached signature contains only the signature, a clear-signed file contains the signed data along with the signature.

Comment: I am comparing a detached signature to the signature part in gpg --clearsign myfile

Comment: With a specific example, or in general?

Comment: See my update. Did I post any sensitive personal information?

Comment: Oh, I see; there’s no sensitive information there, but the clear-text signature is calculated over the canonical form of the file (see the RFC) — if your file isn’t in canonical form, `gpg` will need to alter the signed content. I’ll update my answer to describe this in more detail tomorrow.